# IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP results in "No device found" despite IP_MULTICAST_LOOP (Linux, C++, UDP)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, multicast

First off, I know that there are loads of questions covering multicast topics on here. I also saw that most people's problem is not enabling `IP_MULTICAST_LOOP`. I got that covered already and still end up with a "No device found" error.

I am writing a program that works with the loopback interface or with network devices attached, depending on what the user does hardware wise (plug in or out the cable). I am using UDP for data transfer. I am on Linux and code in C++.

When the network cable is plugged in and, say `eth0` is up and running, everything is fine (my multicast setup works nicely). If only `lo` is available (and up and running, according to `ifconfig`), the call to

`setsockopt(this->socket(), IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &ipmReq, sizeof(ipmReq))`

fails with `-1`, resulting in `errno` reporting "No device found".

Here's the relevant piece of code from my `MulticastEndpoint` class:

```
MulticastEndpoint::MulticastEndpoint(std::string strMulticastGroup, unsigned short usPort) : m_strMulticastGroup(strMulticastGroup), m_usPort(usPort) {
  this->setSocket(::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0));

  memset(&m_saAddrGroup, 0, sizeof(m_saAddrGroup));
  m_saAddrGroup.sin_family = AF_INET;
  m_saAddrGroup.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(m_strMulticastGroup.c_str());
  m_saAddrGroup.sin_port = htons(m_usPort);

  unsigned int unYes = 1;
  bool bOK = false;

  if(setsockopt(this->socket(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &unYes, sizeof(unYes)) >= 0) {
    if(setsockopt(this->socket(), IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, &unYes, sizeof(unYes)) >= 0) {
      memset(&m_saAddrAny, 0, sizeof(m_saAddrAny));
      m_saAddrAny.sin_family = AF_INET;
      m_saAddrAny.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
      m_saAddrAny.sin_port = htons(m_usPort);

      if(bind(this->socket(), (struct sockaddr*)&m_saAddrAny, sizeof(m_saAddrAny)) >= 0) {
        struct ip_mreq ipmReq;
        ipmReq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(m_strMulticastGroup.c_str());
        ipmReq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

        if(setsockopt(this->socket(), IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &ipmReq, sizeof(ipmReq)) >= 0) {
          bOK = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if(!bOK) {
    std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    ::close(this->socket());
    this->setSocket(-1);
  }

  std::cout << this->socket() << std::endl;
}
```

The class is instantiated with the multicast address `224.0.0.1` and the port `2077`. The `setSocket(int)` and `socket()` methods are a simple setter and getter functions storing the socket as an `int` in the instance.

Does anybody have a clue about this? Theoretically, multicast should work on only `lo`, shouldn't it? Also, is maybe the general purpose multicast address I'm using the wrong one? And as far as my understanding of linux sockets goes, `INADDR_ANY` should cover the loopback interface as well. Please correct me if that's wrong under these circumstances.

I'm very grateful for any enlightenment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loopback interface is typically not multicast capable.

If you run `ifconfig -a` when you have `eth0` up and running, you'll see that `eth0` has a flag for `MULTICAST`, while `lo` does not.

Here's what one of my machines displays:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55
          inet addr:10.112.161.84  Bcast:10.112.161.127  Mask:255.255.255.192
          inet6 addr: fe80::211:22ff:fe33:4455/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20001770 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10074436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4589702477 (4.2 GiB)  TX bytes:2896096295 (2.6 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1212663 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1212663 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:60939041 (58.1 MiB)  TX bytes:60939041 (58.1 MiB)
```

EDIT:

In order for this to work, you need to manually turn on multicast on loopback:

```
sudo ifconfig lo multicast
```

Once you do that, you should be able join the multicast group on loopback, however you'll need to specify 127.0.0.1 instead of `INADDR_ANY` for `ipmReq.imr_interface`.